# Combing two pandas dataframes, weaving same columns index/title next to one another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert

I'm trying to combine two dataframes, each with different values under the same column names.

```
A   B   C   D       A   B   C   D
0   0   0   0       2   2   2   2
1   1   1   1       4   4   4   4
2   2   2   2       6   6   6   6
3   3   3   3       8   8   8   8
4   4   4   4       10  10  10  10
```

I'd like to combine the dataframes in such a way that I can have columns side by side, i.e A by A and B by B, and so on, in a new dataframe.

```
A   A   B   B   C   C   D   D
0   2   0   2   0   2   0   2
1   4   1   4   1   4   1   4
2   6   2   6   2   6   2   6
3   8   3   8   3   8   3   8
4   10  4   10  4   10  4   10
```

I've attempted to use a for loop and the .insert function of pandas to little effect (indexing through first df and inserting every other column from the second), the head of each column contains a string and the rest are floats. If anyone could provide some direction or even another library to utilize I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

[image]

An alternative is to add keys to keep track of which one is which and ensure that column groups are kept in same order...

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=[1, 2]).stack(0)[df1.columns].unstack()
```

[image]